# How to save to database with TypeORM in an Interceptor

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I would like to save data to database after every request. I am trying to make a `function` in an `interceptor` but I have some problem with connecting to the `entity`.

This is the beggining of the Interceptor class:

```
@Injectable()
export class TransformInterceptor<T> implements NestInterceptor<T, Response<T>> {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(UserLog) private readonly userLogRepository: Repository<UserLog>) {}
```

This interceptor is not part of any module. This is instantiationed in the `main.ts` file.
This is the error I get:

```
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
app.useGlobalInterceptors(new TransformInterceptor());   
An argument for 'userLogRepository' was not provided.
```

What can I use as a parameter to the `constructor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `useGlobalInterceptors` that does not use the IoC of Nest, you should inject it in your AppModule.

```
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: TransformInterceptor,
    },
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```